# SQL query to find matching subsets

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Students(StudentID, classes, school, advisor)` and I need to find a pair of students that take **exactly** the same set of classes.

For example, in a table:

[image]

I would have an output:

> S3678 and S8978

Because they are both taking the same number of classes (2), and set of classes, French and Logic.

Comment: which database engine?

Comment: what is your sql query and what is the output or error?

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question to inline your table photo and cleaned up some of the formatting. Please check it, and also tag your question with TSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc... whichever you are using

Comment: Thanks so much Brien!! I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If in postgre8.4+, then use the function "array_agg"
- If this is in mySql5.6, then change array_agg() to GROUP_CONCAT(classes).
- If question is in Oracle, then change GROUP_CONCAT() to COLLECT.

> ```
> select t1.studentid
> from 
> (select studentid, array_agg(classes) as classes_set
> from (select studentid, classes from students order by studentid, classes) as st1
> group by studentid) t1
> join (select studentid, array_agg(classes) as classes_set
> from (select studentid, classes from students order by studentid, classes) as st2
> group by studentid) t2
> on t1.classes_set=t2.classes_set and t1.studentid <> t2.studentid
> Result:
> studentid
> S8978
> S3678
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I received an error that GROUP_CONCAT does not exist as a function. Is there an equivalent way of doing this without GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: What is your version of mysql?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL 8.4.20.

Comment: Thanks; I edited my answer for postgreSQL 8.4 version.

Comment: It worked! Thank you vert much!!!! And yea, I am new to array_agg function so I didn't know that would be the way to do it. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Glad it works. Pls accept my answer as well by clicking on the accept button (check). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using T-SQL (initial answer was without knowledge of DBMS the OP was using...):

I would use a [common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to solve this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT StudentID, COUNT(Classes) numOfClassesTaken, 
        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Classes
               FROM Students s2
               WHERE s2.StudentID = s1.StudentID
               ORDER BY ', ' + Classes
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as ClassList
    FROM Students s1
    GROUP BY StudentID)
, matchingClasses AS (
    SELECT numOfClassesTaken, ClassList
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY numOfClassesTaken, ClassList
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

SELECT t1.StudentID, t1.ClassList 
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN matchingClasses t2 ON t1.numOfClassesTaken = t2.numOfClassesTaken AND t1.ClassList = t2.ClassList
```

[image]

[[DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/FPZLI83090)